# Messenger webhook error (curl_errno = 28)

Tags: facebook, api, curl, messenger

Here's my node.js codes

```js
var fs = require("fs"),
    https = require("https"),
    express = require("express"),
    app = express();

https.createServer({
    ca: fs.readFileSync("sslcert/cpanel.ca"),
    key: fs.readFileSync("sslcert/cpanel.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("sslcert/cpanel.crt"),
}, app).listen(444, function() {
    console.log("I'm working :)");
});

app.get("/webhook/", function(req, res) {
    if (req.query["hub.verify_token"] === "token") {
        res.send(req.query["hub.challenge"]);
    } else {
        res.send("Error, wrong validation token");
    }
});
```

And I'm always getting this error on Facebook's "New Page Subscription" page.

```
The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 28; curl_error = Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received; HTTP Message = Unknown Response Code
```

Something wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when https://host:port/ is not accessible. Make sure the URL is accessible from outside of your firewall.

Comment: The port which I use in nodeJS was blocking from the firewall. I allowed this port and it fixed. Thank you so much.

Comment: I got same error, i m trying locally. It's very difficult to understand new facebook version api